# What symbols have been used to represent planets (in the solar system, or other)

Tags: symbols, symbolism

The [Wikipedia page on gender](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender)
 states that the male and female symbols are symbols for the planets Venus and Mars. I wonder whether other planets in the solar system or other also have planet symbols.

Gender symbols intertwined:

[image]

The red (left) is the female Venus symbol. The blue (right) represents the male Mars symbol.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All of the planets, as well as the sun and the moon, have symbols ....

[image]

https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/680/solar-system-symbols/

In fact, some planets have multiple symbols, depending on context. Astrology tends to use differing symbols for Uranus and Pluto and slight variations for Mercury, Saturn, and Neptune.

[image]